# Same regex giving different results

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

This is regarding a regex that tries to identify different parts of an SQL delete statement.

Please check the regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/pezo8h/2/)

```
DELETE\s*(?P<table_alias>[a-zA-z_0-9]*)\s*FROM\s*(?P<table_name>[a-zA-z_0-9]+)\s([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)\s*(?P<where_statement>WHERE){0,1}(\s.)*?
```

And this piece of [code](https://repl.it/repls/CautiousPushyTruespace) in repl.it

```
import re

regex = r'DELETE\s*(?P<table_alias>[a-zA-z_0-9]*)\s*FROM\s*(?P<table_name>[a-zA-z_0-9]+)\s*([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)\s*(?P<where_statement>WHERE){0,1}(\s.)*?'

test_str = 'DELETE FROM my_table1 t_ WHERE id in (1,2,3)'

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

print([m.groupdict() for m in matches])
```

This gives the output (which is also the expected output):

```
[{'table_alias': '', 'table_name': 'my_table1', 'where_statement': 'WHERE'}]
```

However, when I run the same code in my machine I get the following result

```
[{'table_alias': '', 'table_name': 'mytable1', 'where_statement': None}]
```

Note: I am running Python 3.6.4 in a 64 bit windows machine.
The repl.it link above is executed in python 3.6.1

Edit: The question is what should be changed in the regex to make it give the same result in both the platforms.

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: Prepend *why* to title. @sophros

Comment: Edited the post to clearly state the question.

Comment: Instead of built-in `re` library, you may want to try `regex` library on instead, it is way better and maybe gives you consistent results. `pip install regex`.

Comment: I am running Python 3.6.4 on 64 bit Windows 10 machine, and I get the expected output when running your code.

Comment: I use windows server 2012 R2

Comment: I think the issue is with the platform. I tried the same with latest Anaconda set up also. Got the same output as before and not the expected output. Have filed a bug with python community. You can track it here.

https://bugs.python.org/issue34315